# Unable to overcome the "Can't retrieve entity config" error

Tags: configuration, xml, debugging

I have been working on a simple module and have been stuck with the error

**Can't retrieve entity config**

for too long. I am assuming that this is to do with the way I have set my config.xml files up?

The module is to extract information from a table that I have put in to the database. I guessed this would be an easy and basic project for me but i'm really struggling.

My two questions are

1. How should I go about de-bugging projects in Magento (many of my
   problems have been with the xml). So far I have been using `var_dump()`
   and `die()` commands, is there a better way?
2. How do I resolve this problem? (I have added my xml code below)

`namespace/module/etc/config.xml`

```
<global>
    <models>
        <prefcentre>
            <class>Ps_Prefcentre_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>prefcentre_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </prefcentre>

        <prefcentre_mysql4>
            <class>Ps_Prefcentre_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <prefcentre>
                    <table>prefcentre</table>
                </prefcentre>
            </entities>
        </prefcentre_mysql4>  
    </models>
    <resources>
        <prefcentre_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </prefcentre_write>
        <prefcentre_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </prefcentre_read>
    </resources>
</global>
```

======EDIT=====

Cache is disabled.

```
class Ps_Prefcentre_Model_Mysql4_Preferences
extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('prefcentre/preferences', 'prefcentre_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error is generated in this method `Mage_Core_Model_Resource::getTableName()`. You end up in that method usually by calling the `_init()` method from the collection constructor.
Check how that method looks like in `Ps_Prefcentre_Model_Mysql4_Prefcentre_Collection` (something like that).
It should look like this:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('prefcentre/prefcentre', 'TABLE_PK_NAME_HERE');
}
```

The first parameter (`prefcentre/prefcentre`) means the following:
what's before `/` represents the main model class, the name of the tag right under `<models>` tag. In your case `<prefcentre>`. What's after the `/` is the node name under `prefcentre_mysql4->entities`, and before the `<table>` tag. In your case also `prefcentre`
See my comments below directly on your config file section:

```
<models>
    <prefcentre><!-- this tag goes before the slash -->
        <class>Ps_Prefcentre_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>prefcentre_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </prefcentre>

    <prefcentre_mysql4>
        ...
        <entities>
            <prefcentre><!-- this tag goes after the slash -->
                <table>prefcentre</table>
            </prefcentre>
        </entities>
    </prefcentre_mysql4>  
</models>
```

And make sure you clear the cache after modifying something in `config.xml`

Comment: Marius thanks for your reply. I have tried to add prefcentre after the / in the Ps_Prefcentre_Model_Mysql4_Preferences file, but I recieved the same error. Could you please offer any further advice

Comment: You should add it in the collection model `Ps_Prefcentre_Model_Mysql4_Preferences_Collection`.

Comment: I have now got it working, looks like i will have to spend sometime understanding why. Could you offer any advice on question 1. best ways to de-bug magento projects?

Comment: maybe this helps for debugging: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429

Comment: @Marius 
I am exactly having the same issue on live site (at local and on stage its working fine) I even added table PK in collection as you mentioned above but still getting the same issue.
in config
....
<csvheaders>
    <table>csv_file_headers</table>
</csvheaders>
....
in collection
$this->_init("fileimport/csvheaders", "csvfileheaders_id");

Everything seems to be fine but on live server getting this error.
error on live    a:5:{i:0;s:51:"Can't retrieve entity config: fileimport/csvheaders";i:1;s:4970:"#0

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown in `Mage_Core_Model_Resource::getTableName()` as Marius suggested and there can be multiple reasons for that because the method is used in many places in the Magento codebase.

Besides your config XML file you must pay attention to data stored in database - in your case I suspect your custom entity type (check the `eav_entity_type` table) to be improperly configured in DB - most probably an empty or misconfigured `entity_table` column.